# Can web server be an actor in use case diagram of online game?

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram

I am designing an online game in which server records the shots, inform players and pass turn. Can I consider Server as an actor or it should be a part of my system?

Answer (score 1):

Shortly your server is a part of you system

As for identification actors itself you should answer for next questions:

- Who will supply, use, or remove information from the system?
- Who will use the system?
- Who is interested in a certain feature or service provided by the system?
- Who will support and maintain the system?
- What are the system's external resources?
- What other systems will need to interact with the system under development?

So users (players, admins and so on), external sources (i.e. used external API) are actors definatily in your case.

Server can be an actor. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938331/server-as-an-actor-in-use-case-diagram-for-mobile-application) is an example. As you can see server is out side of system.

It can be difficult to idenify all actors immediately but you can revise your use cases (and actors) during creation system.

Given from [source](http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/openup/practice.tech.use_case_driven_dev.base/guidances/guidelines/identify_and_outline_actors_and_ucs_BB5516A9.html)